# Time.use_zone is not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So right now it is 2:54 PM PST in San Francisco. For some reason, this code block is not returning 12:54 PM HST in Hawaii. Am I missing something here? I would expect this code to return me the current time in Hawaii

```
Time.use_zone('Hawaii') do
  Time.now
end
# => 2012-01-03 14:54:54 -0800
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This should work ok:

```
Time.use_zone('Hawaii') do
  p Time.zone.now
end
```

Answer (score 11):

Try using `Time.now.in_time_zone` inside your block instead.

```
> Time.use_zone('Hawaii') do
>   Time.now.in_time_zone
> end
 => Tue, 03 Jan 2012 13:07:06 HST -10:00
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `Time.current` if you want `now` with timezone support. `Time.now` is dangerous when working in a timezone aware application, as a rule of thumb I never use `Time.now`, only `Time.current`. Rails time helpers like `2.hours.ago` and `4.days.from_now` are based off of `Time.current` as well.

```
# Time.current will use Time.zone when needed (when Time.zone is present)
def current
  ::Time.zone ? ::Time.zone.now : ::Time.now
end
```

Also, this is a great article with a great cheat sheet at the bottom: https://www.varvet.com/blog/working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails/

#### DOs

|  | code | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | `2.hours.ago` | Thu, 27 Aug 2015 14:39:36 AFT +04:30 |
|  | `1.day.from_now` | Fri, 28 Aug 2015 16:39:36 AFT +04:30 |
|  | `Time.zone.parse("2015-08-27T12:09:36Z")` | Thu, 27 Aug 2015 16:39:36 AFT +04:30 |
|  | `Time.current` | Thu, 27 Aug 2015 16:39:36 AFT +04:30 |
| When supliyng an API | `Time.current.utc.iso8601` | 2015-08-27T12:09:36Z |
| If you can’t use Time.zone.parse | `Time.strptime("2015-08-27T12:09:36Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z").in_time_zone` | Thu, 27 Aug 2015 16:39:36 AFT +04:30 |
| If you really can’t have a Time or DateTime for some reason | `Date.current` | Thu, 27 Aug 2015 |
| If you have a date and want to make the best out of it | `Date.current.in_time_zone` | Thu, 27 Aug 2015 00:00:00 AFT +04:30 |

#### DON’Ts

|  | code | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Returns system time and ignores your configured time zone. | `Time.now` | 2015-08-27 14:09:36 +0200 |
| Will assume time string given is in the system’s time zone. | `Time.parse("2015-08-27T12:09:36Z")` | 2015-08-27 12:09:36 UTC |
| Same problem as with Time.parse. | `Time.strptime("2015-08-27T12:09:36Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")` | 2015-08-27 12:09:36 UTC |
| This could be yesterday or tomorrow depending on the machine’s time zone, see [issue 1](https://github.com/ramhoj/time-zone-article/issues/1) for more info. | `Date.today` | Thu, 27 Aug 2015 |

Answer (score 5):

Time.now - using server time 
Time.zone.now - using rails application time (in config: config.time_zone) 
Time.use_zone - using 'your' timezone for given block

This example is wrong, because Time.now get time in your server timezone and with method in_time_zone translate time into an equivalent time in Hawaii timezone. But it's no current Time in Hawaii! It's your server time with utc offset for Hawaii.

```
Time.use_zone('Hawaii') do
  Time.now.in_time_zone
end
=> Wed, 14 Aug 2013 10:33:18 HST -10:00 

Time.now.in_time_zone
=> Thu, 15 Aug 2013 00:32:30 MSK +04:00
```

For getting time in Hawaii timezone you must use

```
Time.use_zone('Hawaii') do
  Time.zone.now
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Time.now` this is using your local time zone instead use `Time.current`

```
Time.use_zone('Hawaii') do
  p Time.current
end
```