# Why Time.now returns PST if my TIme.zone is UTC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

In my Rails app I do the following:

```
Time.zone.name #=> 'UTC'
```

Why when I do:

```
Time.parse('2014-12-19').end_of_day.to_datetime
```

I get: `Fri, 19 Dec 2014 23:59:59 -0800`

And when I do:

```
Time.use_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)') { Time.parse('2014-12-19').end_of_day.to_datetime }
```

I get the exact same thing: `Fri, 19 Dec 2014 23:59:59 -0800`

Why is the zone not being applied?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Time.zone.parse` to make it use the proper timezone.

```
2.1.3 (main):0 > Time.zone.name
=> "UTC"
2.1.3 (main):0 > Time.zone.parse('2014-12-19').end_of_day.to_datetime
=> Fri, 19 Dec 2014 23:59:59 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this

`Time.use_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)') { Time.parse('2014-12-19').end_of_day.to_datetime.in_time_zone}`

This would give you the correct time zone. For more information on this have a look at [THIS SO QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719778/time-use-zone-is-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably on Windows, which has a bug in Rails and Rails will always return your local time zone. See [How does Rails know my timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814847/how-does-rails-know-my-timezone)

You can also use

```
zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Hawaii']
zone.at(Time.now)
=> Tue, 16 Jun 2015 09:22:53 HST -10:00
```

But I rather like Pamio's idea

```
Time.now.in_time_zone('Hawaii')
=> Tue, 16 Jun 2015 09:43:17 HST -10:00
```