# How does Rails know my timezone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How does Rails know my time zone? I don't have it set in `application.rb`:

```
# config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

I searched the whole app for `time_zone` and that is the only instance of it. I don't see any environment variables for time zone set either. I'm on Windows.

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\MyBestBody>rails runner "p Time.now"
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
2015-06-12 23:38:33 -0400
```

It prints UTC time when deployed to Heroku.

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\MyBestBody>heroku run rails console
Running `rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.1949
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.1)
irb(main):001:0> Time.new
=> 2015-06-13 03:28:34 +0000
```

#### Rails 4.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From gettimeofday(), or so the [ruby MRI source](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/ident?i=gettimeofday) would have me believe:

```
int __cdecl
gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz)
{
     FILETIME ft;

     GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);
     filetime_to_timeval(&ft, tv);

     return 0;
}
```

Per comment, this is a C function, called by the ruby date routines under the hood. You do not call the method yourself, rather you call the ruby methods you are calling.

Comment: Can you explain that more? I'm not calling `#gettimeofday`. That function also seems to make use of a file handle, which I'm not using either. And how can I change it? I set `config.time_zone = 'UTC'`  but it's still showing `-04:00`!

Comment: Make sure you restart your server or console after you've made the config change.

Comment: Translation for above: "Ruby uses the C level APIs provided by the operating system to get the current time." The current time includes the time zone. The operating system knows what the time zone is. There is a bug in Rails/Ruby that does not strip/translate the time zone information on Windows. Will post another question on how to change time zone in Rails on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Your question  involves two separate things.

The first is what ruby thinks the time zone is. This is the zone used when you use things like`Time.now` or `Time.mktime`. Ruby uses the C level APIs provided by the operating system to get this information (the TZ environment variable can override this on unixy operating systems).

The second is the time zone your users will see when they use your app. This is frequently not the same thing. Even if your users were all in the same timezone it's a good idea to have your servers use UTC because it is free from things like daylight savings time.

For this reason rails has its own timezone system and the setting you found controls the default value of that timezone. Sometimes you might overwrite this on a per user basis. Rails always records information in UTC, but it will be displayed in views using the value of `Time.zone` (And input from forms is interpreted in that zone). You can see what the current time in this zone is by doing

```
Time.zone.now
```

Comment: `rails runner "p Time.zone.name"`: `"UTC"`