# How do I change the Rails timezone on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm unable to change the timezone on Windows. It always gives my local time zone. It works on Heroku.

`application.rb`

```
# config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

Console

```
>rails runner "p Time.zone.name;p Time.now"
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
"UTC"
2015-06-16 14:30:05 -0400
```

Change

`application.rb`

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

Console

```
>rails runner "p Time.zone.name;p Time.now"
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
"UTC"
2015-06-16 14:34:03 -0400
```

See [How does Rails know my timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814847/how-does-rails-know-my-timezone/30814890) for backstory.

Rails 4.2.1, Windows 8.1

Comment: Is your call to config.time_zone commented out or is that just how you typed it into the question?

Comment: In the first case, yes it is commented. In the second case, no it is not commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time.now returns the time from you system clock. You can test this by going into Windows and changing the timezone. You'll find that Time.now has different values depending on the setting.

Time.zone.now will return the time based on your rails application setting.