# Time.use_zone is ignored during active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timezone

The time is currently 12:33PM in San Francisco.

`irb(main):027:0> Time.use_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)") { puts Time.zone.now }
2017-10-19 12:33:06 -0700`

`Time.use_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)") { Event.where("starts_at >= ?", Time.zone.now) }
Event Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (starts_at >= '2017-10-19 19:33:22.532660')`

Judging from the docs and [previous SO threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719778/time-use-zone-is-not-working-as-expected), this appears to the be correct usage. What am I missing?

UPDATE:

Adding `to_s` to the AR query used the correct time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning this specific query you shouldn't be too worried. The `SELECT` query converted your `Time.zone.now` to UTC, but so does everything else that heads to your database.

This happens because Rails converts all datetimes to store (and lookup) in the database to UTC by default. When your time is 12:33PM it's 19:33 UTC.

Comment: If you want to store the local time in the DB you can add `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` in your app config.